# How to execute a third party jar using maven

Tags: java, maven, jar, liquibase

I am using [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/index.html) (via its [Maven plugin](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/maven/index.html)) to handle database migrations.

However not all Liquibase features are available via Maven. One in particular, [Generate Changelog](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/generating_changelogs.html), is only available via the [command line](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/command_line.html) (using the downloadable liquibase.jar) with a command like this:

```
java -jar liquibase.jar \
--driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver \
--classpath=\path\to\classes:jdbcdriver.jar \ 
--changeLogFile=com/example/db.changelog.xml \
--url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE" \ 
--username=scott \ 
--password=tiger \ 
generateChangeLog
```

How can I execute this command via Maven, portably? That is, I do not want to have to add the liquibase.jar file to my project structure.

Instead, I would like to list it as a dependency (I could manually add the jar to my local repository or Nexus proxy) and then reference it when using something like the [Exec Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/)'s `exec:java` or `exec:exec` goals, but I can't see how to do this using an executable jar with those goals. :(

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know, but may be this will help you.

Try to use maven exec plugin and put as a mainClass configuration param this: liquibase.integration.commandline.Main

I get it from MANIFEST.MF from your jar file

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        ...
        <goals>
          <goal>java</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <mainClass>liquibase.integration.commandline.Main</mainClass>
      <arguments>
        <argument>--driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</argument>
        <argument>--changeLogFile=com/example/db.changelog.xml</argument>
        ...
      </arguments>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Aha, I didn't think to check the manifest to get the class name, thanks. I have it working now: It turns out that I did not need to manually download and add the liquibase jar to my repository - it is available already in Maven Central as the [`liquibase-core`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.liquibase/liquibase-core) artifact. So I set liquibase-core as a dependency and it executes perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: @RyanBennetts Note, liquibase-core as a *dependency* will execute the call on program startup. If you want to convert maven to a liquibase frontend, and thus include the db management into your build scripts, then you have to include it as a *plugin*.